# rationale for book's solution of combinatorics question about scheduling ten speakers with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If A, B, C are among $10$ people speaking at a function in alphabetical order What are total ways of doing so.

BOOKS APPROACH: There are $10$ people out of which $3$  need to be taken care of. So total ways are $\frac{10!}{3!}$. And nothing is given beyond it it's such a vague APPROACH. Hope somebody helps me in understanding it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If all the people spoke in alphabetical order, there would only be one possible arrangement.  Judging by the answer, the question means that we wish to count the number of speaking schedules in which A, B, and C appear in alphabetical order.

**Method 1:**  We choose three of the ten speaking slots for A, B, and C.  Since they must appear in alphabetical order, there is only one way to arrange them in the three chosen slots.  The other seven people can be arranged in the remaining slots in $7!$ ways.  Hence, the number of possible speaking schedules in which A, B, and C appear in alphabetical order is 
$$\binom{10}{3} \cdot 7! = \frac{10!}{3!7!} \cdot 7! = \frac{10!}{3!}$$

**Method 2:**  There are $10!$ ways to schedule the speakers.  There are $3! = 6$ orders in which A, B, and C can appear.  Only one of these orders is alphabetical.  By symmetry, the number of speaking schedules in which A, B, and C appear in alphabetical order is 
$$\frac{10!}{3!}$$